# Aggregate functions in Entity framework 3.5

Tags: .net, entity-framework

How can we aggregate function (MIN, MAX, COUNT etc) in Entity framework 3.5 in .net.

Thanks
Ashwani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're already there in the LINQ API. Just use them. E.g.:

```
var count = Context.People.Count();
```

...will get translated to a SQL `COUNT`.

Comment: Will it? Wouldn't it just return number of entities in current in memory collection?

Comment: @Anderson: No, it will not. Use the `Local` property if that's what you're after.